# Is 'terse conciseness' redundant?

Tags: concision

According to OED, the most common use of "terse" is:

> Freed from verbal redundancy; neatly concise; compact and pithy in
>   style or language.

I've see some usage of **terse conciseness**, or **terse brevity**, or similar constructions. To me that seems redundant, even ironic. Am I wrong?

Comment: Seems redundant to me too.

Comment: Even though there's often an overlap in meaning, *terse* and *concise* relate to different aspects. There is no redundancy *per se* in using both. ...

Comment: ... Terseness is only about being brief; economy of words (and thought). A terse statement is not very informative. OTOH, conciseness is about packaging in a compact way, conveying all the information in whatever brevity that may be possible.

Comment: I agree that *concise* implies a comprehensiveness, similar to the way *succinct* does, but some definitions (including the Oxford English Dictionary, as quoted above) use *concise* and *pithy* in the definition. Putting that aside, even if the nuances between *terse* and *concise* are as you say, the examples given in the question would still be redundant. Unless the intended effect is to apply a connotation of rudeness or curtness to the *conciseness*, *terse* doesn't add anything that *conciseness* doesn't already have. Redundant.

Comment: *terse* expresses also the tone, the manner of the concision/conciseness.  *Terse* (to me) is about being abrupt, verging on impoliteness, it has negative connotations whereas conciseness does not. As a result I don't consider the expression to be redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redundant? Almost completely.

These words overlap 90%, and the tiny 10% difference isn't really enough to avoid being redundant, even if a shred of difference is truly present. Redundancy is measured in degree of overlap versus the degree of separation.

Second problem: these words tug their connotations in opposite directions, which muddles the already tortured meaning.

Conclusion: zero style points for using these together. Their incomplete overlap is a technicality. They are redundant enough.

BTW: this is a great family of synonyms relating to bevity of language:

*) **Terse** is tense and possibly rude. Brief, yes, but not in a good way.

*) **Succinct** speaks lucidly. Brief, yet clear.

*) **Concise** contains a lot despite its small size. Brief, yet comprehensive.

*) **Laconic** is just brief; it doesn't hint at other virtues. Unlike terseness, its connotation is usually neutral, and it alone is useful among this synonym family for describing an individual's personality generally (versus their specific words).

Answer (score 1):

> Is 'terse conciseness' redundant?

Yes, I think so.

Although it probably depends on how finicky you want to be about it. If I had to pick some differences, and at the risk of rephrasing what tralston already stated;

*Brevity* is surely a subset of both *terse* and *concise*, so *terse brevity* is almost certainly redundant.

With regards to *terse conciseness*; the two words seem to overlap but don't have identical meanings, so *terse conciseness* has a different meaning (or at least connotation) to either *terse* or *concise*.

[Terse](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/terse) means brief and cut short, it has negative connotation as it is usually associated with rudeness.

[Concise](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/concise) implies clarity and a sparse use of words to describe something succinctly. It tends to be used to describe positive traits.

I would interpret *terse conciseness* to mean a form that is short, with meaning conveyed but with a potentially negative demeanour.

Here are some examples to illustrate how I view the differences, in response to "what are you up to?"

1. Terse "Stuff! Leave me alone."
2. Concise "I am building a play-house and don't want to be distracted"
3. Terse Conciseness "I am building a play-house. Leave me alone!"